# query the latest SMS messages group by contact

Tags: android, sql, android-contentprovider

Like the Message app, the first Activity displays the lastest SMS grouped by person and the count number.

Example I had exchanged 50 texts with Chris, 60 with Aline, 40 with Ray ...
The app displays something like this

> ```
> Chris (50) Hey how are you lately ?    
> Aline (60) Let's catch up     
> Ray   (40) Here is my number
> Ethan (1)  I wrote a solution
> ```

I'm trying to do the same . I query all the SMS then I sort them.
At least it's O(n) efficient .

```
Cursor cur = this.getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://sms"), null, null, null, null);
int count = cur.getCount();

// iterate all the SMS
for (int i=1 ; i<=count ; i++){
    // processing
    ....

    cur.moveToNext();
}
```

Is there a way to **query** the latest messages (received or sent no draft type) grouped by person and get the number of SMS from a person ?
I suppose there are multiple queries.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think this will do what you want:

```
Cursor cur = this.getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse( "content://mms-sms/conversations?simple=true"), null, null, null, "normalized_date desc" );
```

The returned cursor will contain the latest message in every conversation and the amount of messages in each conversation.

Comment: It works !! The number of messages is the column "message_count". Don't forget the "android.permission.READ_SMS". Where did you get this simple code snippet ?

Comment: I remember stumbling into the exact same issue when doing my own SMS parsing. Did a quick googling and found a few sources actually. Glad it worked.

Comment: Ok thanks for your help. I didn't googled keyword "conversation" :)

Comment: I noticed that these are the columns returned by your query:
(_id,
date,
message_count,
recipient_ids,
snippet,
snippet_cs,
read,
type,
error,
has_attachment) .

Which column corresponds to the contact_id in the Contacts Content Provider?  Or is this not possible with adding the query string "?simple=true"  ?

Comment: Hey @gelupa, how do you get the thread_id from the `Uri` you are using in the query?

Comment: Nevermind, i guess the '_id' column of "content://mms-sms/conversations?simple=true" is equivalent to the 'thread_id' column of "content://mms-sms/conversations" .

Comment: This seems to crash on a Galaxy Note 2 with Android 4.3. The error is `Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: normalized_date (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM threads ORDER BY normalized_date desc` . How can you determine if the normalized_date column does not exist? I have tested this on other versions of android without an issue.